# CKEditor5 insert non-editable text in the editor

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am trying to insert small pieces of text in the CKEditor5, like

```
{{ variable name }}
```

These variables shall not be edited by user. I tried to insert

```
content = '<span contenteditable="false">' + content + '</span>';
```

Using the following code, content is the non-editable string

```
content = '<span contenteditable="false">' + content + '</span>';
const viewFragment = this.editor.data.processor.toView( content );
const modelFragment = this.editor.data.toModel( viewFragment );
this.editor.model.insertContent( modelFragment );
```

It does not work. The wrapping  part is always removed by CKEditor. What should I do to achieve this?

Comment: how about using restricted editing plugin as documented here https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/restricted-editing.html

Comment: By wrapping text you mean the outer span tag?

Comment: @MuhammadTalal yes.

Answer (score 0):

you should configure editor to allow for other tags

and you need html Editing plugin (sorry I forgot the real name of it)

```
public config = {
    placeholder: 'content here',
    htmlSupport: {
      allow: [
        {
          name: /.*/,
          attributes: true,
          classes: true,
          styles: true
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```